# From where does reducer get the current state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I was redux and came across the term reducer and then I found this article https://daveceddia.com/what-is-a-reducer/ explaining how reducer works. But what confused is this statement in that article:

```
(state, action) => newState

As in: it takes the current state, and an action, and returns the newState.
```

The question is from where does reducer receives the current state?

Comment: why would it have to receive the state from anywhere, I mean reducer is the one who stores the state in the store. It already had the previous state and the when a new payload comes with the action it just updates the state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [redux docs](https://redux.js.org/glossary#reducer):

```
type Reducer<S, A> = (state: S, action: A) => S
```

> Reducers calculate a new state given **the previous state** and an action.

Reducers "receives" the state from the previous state.

For what "the previous state" means you can read the related sections [state](https://redux.js.org/glossary#state) and [store](https://redux.js.org/glossary#store).

Comment: Nice that was quite concise answer.

Comment: @Dennis Vash, hi, I just cannot get one thing, where is the previous state stored? Ok, the very first time the previous state will be fallback initial state but since that initial state is immutable. How does reducer remember the previous state?

Comment: There is ["a single source of truth"](https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles/) which is the store - within there is the state object and he is a singleton.

Comment: @Dennis Vash, for example when we dispatch an action for, say, the third time to reducer then how does reducer know the state of the previous dispatch?

Comment: It always references the current state (which called the "previous state" inside the reducer) in the time of dispatch.

Comment: @DennisVash, aha is it true that when the reducer creates the new state immutably, will that newly created state firstly is put into redux store then send that new state to components. Right?

Comment: @DennisVash, sorry Dennis just last thing. I just do not want to fail interview:D. Here is the example code:case 'ADD_LETTER':
      return state + action.letter; so before state + action.letter is returned to subscribed components, state + action.letter is FIRSTLY put into redux store so that next time it can serve as the current state. Am I correct? Pls sorry for re-asking))

Comment: Please just ask another question and post it. 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  its out of the scope of the current one.

Comment: @DennisVash, pls I just have to wait for a whole 90 minutes to create a new question. This is my very last question

Comment: @DennisVash, very briefly))

Comment: Yes, after every action the store is updated and "subscribed" to other components

Answer (score 0):

> The reducer accepts the current state/previous state and an action. According to
>   the action type, it will return new state.

ie; `(state, action) => newState;`